# How to disable default keyboard on android device using action script 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I have a problem in my android air project. I have a text box when i click on it the default keyboard of device will pop up from the bottom of the screen. But the text box which i clicked also will be on the bottom, hence when the keyboard pops up the text box is under the keyboard so my entered text will not be seen and also i don't want to shift the text box to the top of the screen. Please suggest any code for disabling the default keyboard so that i can use my own one where ever i want on the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a text input from requesting the Software Keyboard you should set your `textinput.needsSoftKeyboard` to `false`

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#needsSoftKeyboard